# Проблема с drawImage canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

не появлялась картинка вызванная drawImage,но проблема решилась с помощью addEventListener("load", function() {, но как быть с множеством подобных картинок,которые после их загрузки в цикле for нормально бы появлялись?

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("map");
map = canvas.getContext("2d");
var grass = new Image();
grass.addEventListener("load", function() {
   map.drawImage(grass, 50, 50, 30 , 20);
}, false);
grass.src = '//picsum.photos/200/300';
```

```html
<canvas id="map" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

Comment: Организовать проверку загрузки каждой картинки и начинать работу с холстом только после нее

Comment: А как это примерно реализовать? Мне просто бы для начала обучения немножко готовых реализаций подобного посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-бы работать с картинками на холсте, нужно обязательно дождаться, пока браузер их загрузит. Код у вас правильный, так и надо по сути делать.

Если у вас вопрос в том, как сделать отрисовку в момент загруженности всех картинок, то самый простой способ, это посчитать кол-во картинок, которые загружаются и при загрузке каждой инкрементировать счетчик с проверкой на последнюю, что бы когда загрузилась последняя выполнить нужный код. Например так:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("map");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var images = [];
var countAllImages = 4; // для динамического кол-ва картинок
var countImagesLoaded = 0; // это наш флаг загруженности всех картинок

function drawImagesAfterLoaded() {
  if(countImagesLoaded === images.length) {
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      ctx.drawImage(images[i], 30 * i, 20 * i, 30 , 20);
    }
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < countAllImages; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = '//picsum.photos/200/' + (Math.round(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
  img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    countImagesLoaded++;
    drawImagesAfterLoaded();
  }, false);
  images.push(img);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="map" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
```

В современном мире JS лучше бы использовать конечно [Промисы (Promise)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)